# OkHttp vs Apache (Posting JSON only)

Tags: android, android-networking, okhttp

In my previous projects, I've defaulted to OkHttp. For this project, I'm only looking to post some JSON data every minute or two. Is there any benefit in including/using OkHttp for this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

One benefit would be that you're already familiar with it (thus speeding up your coding time)...